# (Java) How do you do full paths in the File class when you are using Textmate in a macbook?

Tags: java, macos, file-exists

I have a macbook and our school told us to use TextMate if we don't have a pc. I can do this in a pc, but I'm having trouble with the syntax in a mac OS since they are different. This is what I'm using and even though I created a file named `Data.txt`, the prompt that pops up says it doesn't exist.

```
import java.io.File;

class FileClassTutorial
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
      {
     File x= new File("MacintoshHD/Users/Alexis/Desktop/Data.txt");

     if(x.exists())
            System.out.println(x.getName() + " exists!!!");
     else
                System.out.println("This file doesn't exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: TextMate is only the editor you happen to use, right? It does not seem relevant to your question. Java's syntax does not rely on platform - it ought to work the same. Despite your assertion this works on your pc, what is that `newFile` function? I am only passingly familiar with Java but I haven't seen that one yet.

Comment: oops, i made a typo and didn't put a space in between new File while editing to make this legible. I edited it. 

and yes, Textmate is the only editor I have. And you are right, Java doesn't rely on platform, however, the path syntax in a macbook is different than on windows OS. That's the main difference and whats causing me trouble. 

new File is creating an object from where I can use a data.txt file 

in windows, one would use \ when doing a path, 

mac is / 

when you are doing a path for an object in windows for java, you use  //

i'm trying to figure out what I'm suppose to do in mac

Comment: Try omit the "MacintoshHD" part and just use `/Users/..`. Apart from that, there is usually a space in `Macintosh HD`.

Answer (score 0):

`new File("something/other"`) is assumed to be "./something/other" where '.' is the current working directory where jvm is started. It's what you need ?

Otherwise, you can start a path by '/' to have an absolute path from super-root of your file disk